# Failed to load 3rd party library in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, 3rd-party-library

I have a 3rd party library and i put it inside lib/internal folder like this :

[image: library]

but when i call the function in my custom module helper/data.php , i got an error undefined function, here's the helper/data.php :

```
use RocketLabs\SellerCenterSdk\Core\Client;
use RocketLabs\SellerCenterSdk\Core\Configuration;
use RocketLabs\SellerCenterSdk\Core\Request\GenericRequest;
use RocketLabs\SellerCenterSdk\Core\Response\SuccessResponseInterface;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    public function test()
    {
                $request = new GenericRequest(Client::POST,'GetCategoryTree',GenericRequest::V1, [], []);
                print_r($request);
                exit;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://packagist.org/packages/rocket-labs/sellercenter-sdk-php, this library 'dev' branch. But magento need at least 'alpha' version. So open **composer.json** from Magento2 root. edit following line:

```
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
```

**To**

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

After that run following command

```
composer require rocket-labs/sellercenter-sdk-php
```

Now magento automatically load this library.

Comment: is there a way just copy the lib folder without using composer to install the lib?

Comment: This is the magento2 way to install 3rd party library.